# fxLayoutWrap not working

Tags: angular, angular-flex-layout

I've got these blocks of codes

```
<div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutGap="1em" fxLayout.lt-md="column" fxLayoutWrap>
    <div *ngFor="let post of posts; let i=index" >
         <div *ngIf = "i%3===0" fxFlex="90%" fxFlex.lt-md="100%">
             <!--Some code-->
         </div>
         <div *ngIf = "!(i%3===0)" fxFlex="40%" fxFlex.lt-md="100%">
             <!--Some other code-->
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want the stuff to be on the same row when I use `fxFlex="40%"` However, they appear on different rows

Comment: You need `fxFlex="40%" fxFlex.lt-md="100%"` in the same `div` as the `ngFor`, not the child.

Comment: What version of flex-layout are you using? I only discovered the same problem when upgraded my project to 6.0.0-beta.16

Answer (score 35, accepted):

https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/blob/cb0beab46507aa50c513aca8bb6ef632c397035c/CHANGELOG.md#breaking-changes

fxLayoutWrap has been removed. You can use fxLayout options.

```
<div  fxLayout="row wrap"> ... </div>
```

Comment: WOWnderful! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

**`flex-layout 6.0.0-beta.16`**, since **fxLayoutWrap** directive has been **deprecated** in this version

```
<div fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign=" none">
  <div fxFlex="100" fxLayout="row wrap" fxLayoutAlign="space-around stretch" fxLayout.xs="column">
    <div *ngFor="let item of items | async" fxFlex.xs="100" fxFlex.sm="50" fxFlex.md="33" fxFlex.lg="33" fxFlex.xl="33">
     {{item}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Had no problems with fxLayoutWrap in previous versions of flex-layout

Answer (score 1):

**fxLayoutWrap: * [fxLayoutWrap] was deprecated in earlier betas. fxLayoutWrap has now been removed. Developers should use fxLayout options.**

**Before**

```
<div  fxLayout="row" fxLayoutWrap="wrap"> ... </div>
```

**current**

```
<div  fxLayout="row wrap"> ... </div>
```